# logic chip that's hybrid of decoder and shift register?

Tags: digital-logic

Somewhere in the vast array of logic chips that have come out over the past 50 years, are there any with behavior that's kind of like a hybrid between a shift register and 3-to-8 decoder, that can be connected in parallel with a SPI bus to allow up to 8 slaves to share the same 4 wires in scheme kind of like the following?

- SS goes high. The address-decoder chip's outputs all go high (or all go tristate, so they can be pulled high)
- 3 bits are shifted via MOSI and SCK. The slaves ignore it, because their SS lines are all high... but the address-decoding chip silently notes the activity to its internal register.
- SS goes low. The last 3 bits shifted to the internal register act kind of like the input pins on a virtual 74xx138... one of the 8 output pins (corresponding  to 0..7) goes low, the remainder stay high.
- The desired slave has its SS line connected to the address-decoder's output pin corresponding to the 3-bit value we just sent, so its SS line goes low, and it's now listening to us.

Does a chip like this actually *exist* as a relatively cheap commodity logic chip? Or... is there some reason why a scheme like this *isn't* actually practical?

I know you could probably achieve this functionality by using multiple common logic chips... but it just seems like something that would be so fundamentally useful, there almost *has* to be a single chip that "does it all", even if it's a needle in a gigantic haystack of 74xx logic chips.

Comment: You're talking about an IC that changes the serial protocol of everything around it. Way too specific and niche. TBH, it sounds super useless to me. Why wouldn't you throw out the original SS pin and use three GPIO to drive a 3-to-8 decoder for the chip select? Are you just trying to save two GPIO pins?

Comment: Admittedly, the main driving motivation was trying to think up a way to make a universal level-shifting board that implements 3 MOSFET bidirectional lines (for i2c and 1-wire) plus a pair of '125 chips (HCT for 3.3 to 5v, LVC for 5v to 3.3v) and a pair of sn74lvc1t45 in opposite directions (so both sides get at least one whose direction they can control). The problem with SPI is the slippery slope of "how many SS lines do I really need to include (and potentially level-shift) on a "universal" kitchen-sink board. This reduces the required SS lines to 1

Comment: @Bitbang3r I've been doing 7400 series since 1974 and I don't recall anything like that in the series and I don't expect one, either. There have been a number of specialty chips for various MCUs that might do something similar, as well as some other stuff you probably don't want. But not specifically SPI-related, I suspect. Maybe. But I've not seen one. This is the kind of thing, if I were stuck on this idea, where I'd buy a 14-pin MCU (11 or 12 I/O pin) to do it. PIC16F or ATTINY. And they are cheap. About 5 cents per pin in 1s.

Comment: Yeah, my fallback idea was to just implement it with something like an ATTiny2313, or maybe at ATtiny25 whose address (1..255) is hardcoded at flash-time... but I first wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel if there happened to be a perfectly good 74xxx chip already existing for more or less that purpose.

Comment: IIRC, there's something like an 'addressable decoder' , maybe 238 rings a bell, that's a  latch followed by a 138 functionality, but not a S/R followed by 138. You could hook up a 595 and a 138.

Comment: @Neil_UK, the catch with that is you'd probably need at least 2 or 3 additional chips to overload the single SS and make its high/low states (and transitions) trigger the necessary actions on the 595. By that point, you're probably at the point where a cheap CPLD (or maybe something like a 22v10 GAL?) would make more sense. I'm actually kind of intrigued by the 22v10, but so far I've only read horror stories about how it's a rabbit hole that looks deceptively cheap & accessible, but is a complete nightmare in reality.

Comment: @Bitbang3r problem with 22v10 in the past has been lack of a cheap programmer that correctly programs different manufacturers' versions, particularly the Atmel ATF22V10C (which is the only _new_ 22V10 you can get today). I cracked the programming algorithm a few years ago, and now you can program them with a Minipro TL866 II Plus or an Arduino https://github.com/ole00/afterburner   https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/current-inexpensive-programmer-for-22v10_s-16v8_s/

Comment: Even if such a chip would exist, it would break the interface between original SPI driver and original SPI chip. It would still need to be initialized properly to point to default SS output after all the power up glitches on data, clock and select lines. And if the chip or driver does anything custom, like an Arduino accessing two different slaves with two different SS pins or even with different clock phase/polarity settings, there will be clock edges while SS is high. How would your chip even know which clock edge should be used at any given time?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, wow, that's impressive! I'll have to read more about it tonight! Off the top of your head, does this sound like the kind of thing that a 22v10 would be appropriate for and capable of handling (at least, if I dumbed it down slightly to basically just be a glorified 595 that latches and output-enables when CS goes high, and output-disables when CS goes low)? Or is something like that strictly CPLD/FPGA territory?

Comment: @Bitbang3r You need a 3 stage shift register, and 3 to 8 line decoder with 8 outputs. Problem is you need to feed the 3 shift register outputs back into the logic matrix to decode them, and this uses up 3 output pins making a total of 11 but you only have 10. Another thing to consider is that standard GAL22V10's have very high power consumption (~150mA at 5V). I would use 'discrete' logic gates like eg. HC595 + HC138 etc., as they are much lower power and easier to work with. If you want to go HDL then use eg. an XC9536XL.

Answer (score 0):

SPI was developed long after the 74xx series was developed and there are no SPI-dedicated 74x ICs.

The MAX350 performs some of the functions you are describing - xhttps://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/MAX350.html

Comment: I think you have the history of SPI somewhat wrong. As many devices already had bunchs of 74XX chips which the MCU might have needed to access serially by software bit-banging the serial protocol, Motorola just added an hardware module to interface serial peripherals to make the MCU side easier. So SPI was developed because there were already so many different kind of subsystems made from 74XX logic.

Comment: @jp314, oooh... so... tantalizingly... close... the MAX350 is promising, but I think I'd still need at least a NAND to combine CS with the MAX350's output pin (so the slave's SS could only be low while CS remained high). Otherwise, taking CS low and shifting the next address pattern would end up getting seen by BOTH the MAX350(s) *and* the slave currently selected by the MAX350's output pattern. Unless it would allow me to tie CS and RESET together, but I suspect shifting while RESET is low isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a chip like this actually exist as a relatively cheap commodity
> logic chip?

Probably not. The closest I could find is the [LTC1390](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1390fs.pdf), which is an 8 to 1 **analog** multiplexer with 3 wire serial interface. The analog switches could be used as 'open drain' outputs with pullup resistors, and the logic levels *seem* to match up with what you want, but I wouldn't bet on it working properly.

> Or... is there some reason why a scheme like this isn't actually
> practical?

It's certainly practical, but would typically be done with a few standard TTL gates - which is what the 74xx138 and 74xx595 etc. were made for. Why manufacture specialized chips with limited appeal when customers can just use standard gates configured to their requirements?

This is also what [GAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_array_logic)s and [CPLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_programmable_logic_device)s were made for. If you would rather have a single chip and design the logic in [HDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language) then a small CPLD would do the job, or you could combine standard TTL with a small GAL for a 2 chip solution.